# Mongo Shell only connects with prepended host

Tags: mongodb

I have a new mongodb setup. 
my running mongo process is this:

```
mtp      26776  0.0  0.0   4104   464 ?        S    Apr14   0:41 /command/svscan /home/mtp/service
mtp      26779  0.0  0.0   3932   392 ?        S    Apr14   0:01  \_ supervise mongodb
mtp      14413  0.5  0.2 337744 53660 ?        Sl   14:57   0:04  |   \_ mongod --dbpath /home/mtp/mongodb --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --port 21111 --auth --nohttpinterface --smallfiles
```

I connect to it by main admin:

```
mongo admin --port 21111 -u mtp_mongoadmin -p
```

I create a db

```
$use errbit-production 
> switched to db errbit-production
```

I create a user on that db which can read and write:

```
db.createUser({user: "mtp-production", pwd: "blah", roles:["readWrite"]})
```

But I cannot connect

```
$ mongo --port 2111 --host localhost -u mtp-production -p
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12
Enter password:
connecting to: localhost:2111/test
2016-04-18T15:14:44.607+0200 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:2111, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-04-18T15:14:44.608+0200 Error: couldn't connect to server localhost:2111 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed
```

The only way I can connect is by this

```
$ mongo localhost:2111/errbit-production -u mtp-production -p
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12
Enter password:
connecting to: localhost:2111/errbit-production
>
```

Why is this? And how can I solve this?

Comment: Not sure if it is just a typo or not, but your middle connection refused example is missing a 1 in the port number, hence the error

Comment: only a typo here at SO. I corrected.